# Manipulating/adding fields to exif-data iptc

Tags: image, metadata, exif, iptc

when looking into metadata of images I was wondering how standardized this data actually has to be. Is it possible to add a custom field for an application? I understand that it might be not readable by common applications but what way would you suggest to add some custom meta-data as in
"Custom value: 1000"
? 
thx for your suggestions, links, info, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMP supports custom namespaces and fields - but I don't think EXIF or IPTC do.

See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html for further documentation